# Full expression friendly calculator app?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation

One of the apps I miss most from Linux when using a Mac is the [Gnome calculator (gcalctool)](https://live.gnome.org/Gcalctool/). I like that I can type out a full expression before evaluating it:

[image]

Is there a good free calculator app that works similarly or is there a way to install gcalctool?

Comment: I love Ubuntu 10.04 LTS <3

Comment: It's not free, nor quite the same as gcalctool, but I recommend at least taking a look at [Soulver](http://www.acqualia.com/soulver/) for the Mac; best calculator app ever. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[gcalctool](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=gcalctool) is available in [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts)

1. Download and [install MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/install.php)
2. Perform the following action to install gcalctool from within a Terminal:

   `sudo port install gcalctool`

Answer (score 2):

I am lucky enough to have a Mathematica license, but if I didn't, I would solve problems like this using Spotlight or bc.

1. Click on the Spotlight icon in the upper right and enter your math problem rather than a string to search for.  2+8*6^.5  immediately returns 21.595 . . .
2. the bc app in the terminal works similarly, though I have found bugs in it and it wouldn't be my first choice.